# Linux(on BeagleBone) can not find the files inside SD card after setup root password

Tags: linux, beagleboard, beagleboneblack

I have a Beaglebone that is running linux. And I put some files inside of an SD card that is inserted into the board. Today I just setup a root password. After reboot, I can not find any files inside of the SD card folder anymore when I am doing remote access as root user using PuTTY. If I delete the root password, the files appear again. Can anyone tell me why it is happening?

Eddit:
When I do not have a password, I use 'df' to show the discs it shows like this:

root@beaglebone:/etc# df

Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on

rootfs           1738184 1046980    601240  64% /

/dev/root        1738184 1046980    601240  64% /

devtmpfs          255160       0    255160   0% /dev

tmpfs             255292       4    255288   1% /dev/shm

tmpfs             255292     244    255048   1% /run

tmpfs             255292       0    255292   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

tmpfs             255292       4    255288   1% /tmp

/dev/mmcblk1p1     71133   55238     15895  78% /media/BEAGLEBONE

/dev/mmcblk0p1  31155232    2880  31152352   1% /media/UNTITLED

After I setup a password the bottom two disappeared(the last one is my 32G SD Card).

Comment: Please post your /etc/fstab file.

Comment: rootfs               /                    auto       defaults              1  1
proc                 /proc                proc       defaults              0  0
devpts               /dev/pts             devpts     mode=0620,gid=5       0  0
tmpfs                /tmp                 tmpfs      defaults              0  0

Comment: @user3047771 It seems you don't mount the sdcard when you boot.

Comment: Oh, I have to re-mount the SD card? I will try this, thank you very much.